# If Statements with Selenium using find element by xpath (contains text)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find an element by text and depending if it is found or not print an output to the screen

This is what I have so far but I just cant get it to work

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'addFromWishlist')]").isEmpty()
{
System.out.println("In stock");
}
else{
  System.out.println("Not In Stock");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use `find_elements  (plural)` so that it would `return a list of web element` if **found**, if not it will `return empty list`. either way there won't be any **exception**.

```
try:
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'addFromWishlist')]")) >0 :
        print('In stock')
    else:
        print('Not In Stock')
except:
    print('Something went wrong')
    pass
```

Comment: So that worked if it was in stock 

but if not in stock selenium threw up an exception and the else never processed

Comment: Impossible, we are using `find_elements`, if it is not in stock,  len will be 0 hence else will get executed.

Comment: NM my mistake it was erroring on an earlier element in my search